# Silverlight The tag .... does not exist in XML namespace

Tags: silverlight, reference, namespaces, controls

I'm struggling with this error:

The tag 'AutoCompleteComboBox' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:ACBComboBox;assembly=ACBComboBox'.

The current code has worked previously. All I have done is to move the project files on my computer to a new location.

I've tried deleting the reference and re-creating it. Intelisense is also happy - it predicts AutoCompleteComboBox in xaml.

Could it be anything to do with folder permissions / security something like that? As I say I've made no changes to the code, I've just moved the whole project to a new folder.

I've had a good read around other posts on this subject but they are all in relation to coding issues, which I'm guessing is not the cause in my case.

Thanks!

Phil.

**EDIT:**
I've made a small test project that shows this error and uploaded it here:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=879880045FD56C3A!764&authkey=!AELgfRp67SUfzAg&ithint=folder%2c

Thanks,

Phil.

**Edit 2**

Below is the XAML code from the test project as requested. Thanks.

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="ACCBTest.Home" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:ACBComboBox;assembly=ACBComboBox"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
Title="Home"
Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PageScrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource PageScrollViewerStyle}">

        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentStackPanel">

            <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderText" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}" 
                               Text="Home"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ContentText" Style="{StaticResource ContentTextStyle}" 
                               Text="Home page content"/>

            <custom:AutoCompleteComboBox/>

        </StackPanel>

    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You need to replace the new namespace with the old one!

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan, sorry I don't understand what I need to do there, could you possibly explain a bit more? As far as I can see the code is identical on the old versions that used to work. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must **Add a reference** for your assembly in the **References** folder of your project, then right click on it --> "**Copy Local**" set to **True**.

Comment: thanks for the post. I've done that but it's not corrected the error. As far as I can see the references are correct, and intelisense picks up everything within them.

Comment: Hi @ChristianAmando, I've posted the xaml code above for a small test project, and I've uploaded the whoel test project too here:

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ChristianAmado, I've put the XAML above and I've put the whole test project here:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=879880045FD56C3A!764&authkey=!AELgfRp67SUfzAg&ithint=folder%2c

thanks!

Comment: Hey Phil, may be the problem is inside ACBComboBox assembly. Have you got this assembly? VB have some problems with project names.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for that. The dll is in the bin/debug folder of the test project I uploaded if you are able to have a look. I think it's okay as I can explore it via the object browser in visual studio - certainly all looks good in it that way. Would I be right in assuming that means it's all okay?